# Hidden weighted vertices

Tags: armature, vertex-weights

I'm a solo Unity dev who primarily uses blender. I've been working on a fully animated enemy in my game, and things have been going great- until I implemented ragdoll physics. Apparently, when the base spine bone gets too far from the overarching parent object, some of the vertices get stretched far away from my mesh.

At first, I thought I had missed some vertices when weight painting, but I re-opened it in blender to check, and everything was where it should be. The problem vertices were still 100% influenced by the spine bone, and the main armature (with no bones selected) still showed as having no influence.

What's more, although my animations involve the spine bone moving all over the place, the vertices are never a problem during my actual animations. It's only a problem when I ragdoll my mesh. I don't have this problem when my main character ragdolls, either.

What am I missing here? Is there anything I'm missing, or anything else that might cause some random vertices to go haywire like this?